# using a global php array in an external .js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a theme framework for wordpress, and I have run into a small problem.

I have a defined a $globals array that stores the current registered post types plus a few special pages for the theme layout options page.

```
$GLOBALS['gc_frame_postTypes'] = array('homepage', 'blog');         
$post_types = get_post_types( '', 'names' ); 
    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
        if ($post_type != "revision" && $post_type != "nav_menu_item" && $post_type != "attachment")
            $GLOBALS['gc_frame_postTypes'][] = $post_type;
        }
```

I have this working for my options page, and it correctly creates all the correct options.

The issue I am having is when I try to apply javascript to improve the look and function of the page.

Here is the functioning .js code that does what I want. it shows and hides the fields depending on the selected layout.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // keeps the new sidebar text block blank
    jQuery("#gc_frame_sidebar_name_new").val("") 

    // Homepage layout Function call
    jQuery.fn.layoutSidebars('homepage');

    // page layout Function call
    jQuery.fn.layoutSidebars('page');

    // blog layout Function call
    jQuery.fn.layoutSidebars('blog');

    // post layout Function call
    jQuery.fn.layoutSidebars('post');



    // Homepage layout Function call on change
    jQuery('#gc_frame_homepage_layout').change(function(){
        jQuery.fn.layoutSidebars('homepage');
    });

    // page layout Function call on change
    jQuery('#gc_frame_page_layout').change(function(){
        jQuery.fn.layoutSidebars('page');
    });

    // blog layout Function call on change
    jQuery('#gc_frame_blog_layout').change(function(){
        jQuery.fn.layoutSidebars('blog');
    });

    // post layout Function call on change
    jQuery('#gc_frame_post_layout').change(function(){
        jQuery.fn.layoutSidebars('post');
    });



});



jQuery.fn.layoutSidebars = function(pageType){
    pageLayout = jQuery("#gc_frame_" +pageType+ "_layout").val();
    if (pageLayout == 'fullwidth'){
        jQuery("label[for^='gc_frame_" +pageType+ "_left_sidebar_']").closest('tr').hide();
        jQuery("#gc_frame_" +pageType+ "_left_sidebar_count").val(0);
        jQuery("label[for^='gc_frame_" +pageType+ "_right_sidebar_']").closest('tr').hide();
        jQuery("#gc_frame_" +pageType+ "_right_sidebar_count").val(0);      
    } else if (pageLayout == 'SB-L') {
        jQuery("label[for='gc_frame_" +pageType+ "_left_sidebar_count']").closest('tr').show();
        jQuery("label[for^='gc_frame_" +pageType+ "_right_sidebar_']").closest('tr').hide();
        jQuery("#gc_frame_" +pageType+ "_right_sidebar_count").val(0);
    } else if (pageLayout == 'SB-R') {
        jQuery("label[for^='gc_frame_" +pageType+ "_left_sidebar_']").closest('tr').hide();
        jQuery("#gc_frame_" +pageType+ "_left_sidebar_count").val(0);
        jQuery("label[for='gc_frame_" +pageType+ "_right_sidebar_count']").closest('tr').show();
    } else if (pageLayout == 'SB-LR') {
        jQuery("label[for='gc_frame_" +pageType+ "_left_sidebar_count']").closest('tr').show();
        jQuery("label[for='gc_frame_" +pageType+ "_right_sidebar_count']").closest('tr').show();
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is take the above global array and get it into the javascript somehow, so that if new custom post types are added they will be affected by the javascript as well.

I currently have the php and javascript in 2 files, and I do not know how to get the information from the php file to the javascript.

Any help would be great

Comment: instead of jQuery keyword you can make it $. i.e $('#gc_frame_post_layout').change instead of jQuery('#gc_frame_post_layout').change

Comment: print it directly into a javascript var, request it with ajax, json encode it and print it to a data attribute, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$_SESSION` variables to share information within your pages.

In your first page, before loading your javascript file:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['globalVar'] = Value;
```

In your external javascript file (with .php extension) you can get this like:

```
<?php session_start(); //at the top of your JavaScript?>
...
var globalVar = '<?php echo $_SESSION['globalVar']; ?>'
...
```

Comment: I added the lines above replacing "Value" with my global array and added an alert to my .js.php file and I get back and Undefined

Comment: Oh! In your second file, you need put `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the top of your file to load your session.

Comment: OK tried that and I still get a blank. I also tried the line var globalVar = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['globalVar']); ?>' and I get a null in my alert now

Comment: You need to put session_start() in both files

Comment: now we are getting somewhere I get ["homepage","blog","post","page"] from my alert now. now I just have to get it formated correctly so I can use it as a javascript array

Comment: Yep, or you can use `var globalVar = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['globalVar']); ?>'` please mark this answer and open a new question if you have.

Comment: when I alert with this line of code alert(globalVar[0]+globalVar[1]+globalVar[2]+globalVar[3]+globalVar[4]+globalVar[5]); I get ["home , how do I get it to load each word between the " as an array value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_localize_script()`

Here's a good resource: http://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/